# Facebook: show open graph dialog when posting expects object reference

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to show the open graph dialog to allow users to write a message before post on their timeline. I'm trying to use the `share_open_graph dialog` but for some reason it says that the action is not referencing the object.

I know that there are some questions about it, but it didn't help me. Also, I would like to know why my second code works (I know that not shows the dialog) and why the first one no, and when I find the solution, why this solution.

This is my code using the Facebook open graph dialog:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'alexdecasa:decorate',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        room: {
            "url": image,
            "title": "Supply title",
            "description": "Supply description",
            "image": image
        }
    })
}, function(response){});
```

My action is `decorate` and the object is `room`. As you can see I'm referencing the object inside the action_properties.

Using `FB.api` code works:

```
FB.api(
    'me/alexdecasa:decorate',
    'post',
    {
        room: {
            "url": image,
            "title": "Supply title",
            "description": "Supply description",
            "image": image
        }
    },
    function(response) {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to create the app in an external `PHP` file and put the meta tags that provides my object.

Now with the `javascript` code like this i can share it without any problem:

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'alexdecasa:decorate',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            room:url
        })
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

As Alejandro-bar figured out, that is the correct way to call the share dialog with Open Graph objects.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'alexdecasa:decorate',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      room:'url-to-my-room',
  })
}, function(response){});
```

The URL from the object you're going to share should include the pertinent open graph metatags in order for the share to work correctly.

The pertinent Facebook documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Important step: Include open graph meta tags on the page at this URL to customize the story that is shared back to Facebook.